# create table with dates - sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that can create a table with dates like below:

```
with digit as (
select 0 as d union all 
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9        
),

seq as (
select a.d + (10 * b.d) + (100 * c.d) + (1000 * d.d) as num
from digit a
    cross join
    digit b
    cross join
    digit c
    cross join
    digit d
order by 1        
)

select (last_day(sysdate)::date - seq.num)::date as "Date"
from seq;
```

How could this be changed to generate only dates

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=53b3dc8590cb4f5389db46b6fe594121)

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT 
        date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) AS first_day_of_month,
        date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month -1 day' AS last_day_of_month   
)
SELECT
    generate_series(first_day_of_month, last_day_of_month, interval '1 day')::date
FROM dates
```

- `date_trunc()` truncates a type `date` (or `timestamp`) to a certain date part. `date_trunc('month', ...)` removes all parts but `year` and `month`. All other parts are set to their lowest possible values. So, the `day` part is set to `1`. That's why you get the first day of month with this.
- adding a month returns the first of the next month, subtracting a day from this results in the last day of the current month.
- Finally you can generate a date series with start and end date using the `generate_series()` function

---

**Edit**: Redshift does not support `generate_series()` with type `date` and `timestamp` but with `integer`. So, we need to create an `integer` series instead and adding the results to the first of the month:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7a8cd7b91ac6401e797621e1d8788ff7)

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT 
        date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) AS first_day_of_month,
        date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month -1 day' AS last_day_of_month   
)
SELECT
    first_day_of_month::date + gs
FROM 
    dates,
    generate_series(
        date_part('day', first_day_of_month)::int - 1, 
        date_part('day', last_day_of_month)::int - 1
    ) as gs
```

Comment: @Adella added a Redshift compatible version

Comment: Phew, actually I have no Redshift instance for testing... Maybe this works? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a906ccefbe66d524ad027c44187b2f29 or this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=914c54a01568e0c3a9667af8a2cc80bf

Comment: That doesn't work? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3ec5f257762a452f3feb213880542d41

Comment: @Adella: The docs from Redshift say this should work if the SELECT is wrapped in parantheses: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_INSERT_30.html So, maybe this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a3174b83b9e56930848cf4d27502cafcl

Comment: Done@S-Man! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You would use `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.dte
from generate_series(date_trunc('month', now()::date),
                     date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day',
                     interval '1 day'
                    ) gs(dte);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d7da7d72d3653ed88adefc3eace3b748) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Generate_series () is a leader node only function in Redshift and cannot be used to store data to a table.  It will produce the correct result but since the request was for a way to create a table this isn't going to meet the need.

Comment: @BillWeiner . . . The question was tagged Postgres -- and Postgres only -- when I answered it.